# Converting JSONB arrays from postgresql to matrices in python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, numpy

I have a table that looks like this -

- **ID** ,
- **Different Table ID** (**foreign key** (one to one connection)),
- **Vector** (**JSONB** array that contain 5000 numerical elements)

Is there a way to query for the first 10000 rows and retrieve (the vectors) as a matrix in python (like a numpy array) efficiently?

Comment: "first" according to what?

Comment: there's one obvious way, have you tried that?

Comment: @jjanes It doesn't matter really..

Comment: @Jasen Iterating over the arrays and building the matrix? Yeah.. I'm asking if there's a more efficient way of doing it

Comment: maybe do list comprehension over a function that returns a list of records.

Comment: Yeah.. I can do that but isn't there a better way of doing it?